# how to generate strings with random lengths

Tags: javascript

```js
function generate(n) {
  const notations = [" U", " D", " R", " L", " F", " B"];
  const switches = ["", "\'", "2"];

  let last = null;
  let scrambles = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    //subtract 1 when you can't select the same as the last
    let available_notations = notations.length - (last === null ? 0 : 1);

    //one random for all combinations
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * available_notations * switches.length);

    let nt = Math.floor(random / switches.length); //notation value
    let sw = Math.floor(random % switches.length); //switch value

    if (last !== null && last <= nt) nt += 1; //add 1 when value bigger than last
    last = nt;

    scrambles += notations[nt] + switches[sw];
  }
  return scrambles;
}
```

so i have this code which will generate random strings like this`B U F' D' F2 L2 R F2 L2 B F' D2 U2 L' D' R' L2 F D R` but they all generate with the same length which is whatever i put as `n` on the for loop

but i want the length to vary from a specfic number until a specfic number like for example i want it to
generate with length of 20 until 25

Comment: What is use of switches here ?

Comment: Instead of passing `n` to the function, you can pass a `min` (e.g. `20`) and a `max` (e.g. `25`) to generate a random `n`. You can [see how on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

I've added an option to add min and max number, with a default value.

```
function generate(nMin = 20, nMax = 25)
```

And then we use the line below to get a random number between min and max

```
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nMax - nMin + 1) + nMin)
```

**Demo**

```js
function generate(nMin = 20, nMax = 25) {
  const notations = [" U", " D", " R", " L", " F", " B"];
  const switches = ["", "\'", "2"];

  let last = null;
  let scrambles = "";
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nMax - nMin + 1) + nMin)
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    //subtract 1 when you can't select the same as the last
    let available_notations = notations.length - (last === null ? 0 : 1);

    //one random for all combinations
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * available_notations * switches.length);

    let nt = Math.floor(random / switches.length); //notation value
    let sw = Math.floor(random % switches.length); //switch value

    if (last !== null && last <= nt) nt += 1; //add 1 when value bigger than last
    last = nt;

    scrambles += notations[nt] + switches[sw];
  }
  return scrambles;
}

document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = generate(20, 25) + '<br/>' + generate(2);
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering, if i only call the function like this ```generate()``` without any values it will default to 20 and 25 right?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

and then call your generator method like

```
var value = generate(getRandomInt(10, 25));
```

Here, 10 is the minimum and 25 is the maximum in range. It will produce various combinations on each execution.